# What is the difference between linking functions and not linking them in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and came across something that felt weird to me. 
The following line did what I expected it to do, it split the string into an array of characters, reversed the array, and put them together again.

```
string.split("").reverse().join("")
```

Now to my question. This did not work the same when I did it over multiple lines, like so:

```
let returnMe = string.split("");
returnMe.reverse();
returnMe.join("");
return returnMe;
```

It seems that the join function did not do its job, because it returns a reversed array of characters that is not glued together to a single string.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `join` doesn't modify the array, it just returns a new string, so you need `returnMe = returnMe.join("")`. `reverse` on the other hand modifies the array directly so you don't need to assign the result to anything to see it.

Comment: To add to Jonas answer you can read on the topic of functional programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the documentation for these methods:

- [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [reverse](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp)
- [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

While reverse does change the original array, split and join return a new one instead. You could do this:

```
let returnMe = string.split("");
returnMe.reverse();
returnMe = returnMe.join("");
return returnMe;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not using what was returned from `.join("")`. `.join` (and a lot of other methods) does not change the array into a string, but rather returns a new string based on the array.

The equivalent to the first would be:

```
 let returnMe = string.split("");
 returnMe = returnMe.reverse();
 returnMe = returnMe.join("");
 return returnMe;
```

Comment: That definately makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: `returnMe.reverse()` is enough. Because `reverse` modifies original array.